# ask user to input numbers and prompt error when user input alphabet MIPS code

Tags: validation, assembly, mips, mips32, qtspim

so currently my code is just as shown below:

```
li  $v0, 4      # printt first
la  $a0, first
syscall

li  $v0, 5      # receive input for first
syscall
add $s0, $v0, $zero # move first to s0
```

Comment: when I input the alphabet the program itself will take it as the number zero and continue to execute.....how am I supposed to make the program exit when an alphabet is entered by user?

Comment: Use the read_string system call (8) and parse the user input yourself.

Comment: If you don't like how syscall 5 works, then use a more primitive one like 8 or 12. These will give you more control at the expense of making you do more of the work.

Comment: let's analyze your code, `syscall 4` means print string frist (we can't see that in your code), then `syscall 5` will read a int from keyboard and add that value to `$s0`. by the time `syscall 5` will receive an alphanumeric value an Error will rise `Runtime exception at 0x00400014: invalid integer input (syscall 5)`

Comment: what is exactly your question?